# Geolocation dont work on a desktop emulator (uwp)

Tags: geolocation, window, win-universal-app

Hello im trying to make a view containing a map in a Universal Windows platform 
i did the fellowing :

```
             using System;
             using System.Collections.Generic;
             using System.IO;
             using System.Linq;
             using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
             using Windows.Foundation;
             using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
             using Windows.UI.Xaml;
             using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
             using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
             using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
            using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
            using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
            using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
            using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;


     namespace Project
         {
          /// <summary>
     /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a                     Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class Geolocation : Page
{
    public Geolocation()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    public async void GetCords()
    {
        Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition pos = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(pos.CivicAddress.City).ShowAsync();
       }
    }
 }
```

but i got a blank page! what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a MapControl in your page, you must:

1. [Create a key](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/) for your map
2. `xmlns:maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps <maps:MapControl`
3. `<maps:MapControl x:Name="map" MapServiceToken="YOUR_TOKEN_HERE" />`

Comment: u saved me a headache or 2 ! thanx a lot it's working perfectly